# unrelated data from the Many-to-Many With a New Entity concept

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Problem summary**

I am getting unrelated data from the Many-to-Many With a New Entity concept for the first two cases.

1. Fetching a particular company and associated users of the company.
2. Fetching particular user and associated company.
3. Not able to feth company and user whose company status is not equal to 3 (CompanyStatus=1 "Pending" ,CompanyStatus=2  "Other",CompanyStatus=1 "Active")

To work on this Many-to-Many With a New Entity concept I have used Company, User, and CompanyUserMapping as an entity.

The blog that I have referred https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many section 4.2

As mentioned above I have created Company, User, and CompanyUserMapping as below

**Company**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long companyId;
    private String companyName;
    private String companyDescription;
    private String companyWebsite;
    private String companyEmailDomain;
    private Integer companyTypeID;
    private Integer numberOfEmployeesID;
    private String companyLogo;
    private Integer companyStatus;
    private Boolean active;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<CompanyUserMapping> companyUserMapping;     
}
```

**User**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String encryptedEmail;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String userStatus;
    private String guid;
    private Boolean isNotlocked;
    private Date lastLogin;
    private String profilePic;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<CompanyUserMapping> companyUserMapping; 
}
```

**CompanyUserMapping**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class CompanyUserMapping {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long companyUserMappingId;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id") 
    private Company company;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") 
    private User user;

    private String role;
    private String [] authorities;
    private boolean isExternal;
    private boolean isActive;
    private Long customerId;
}
```

Then I inserted two companies and a user in each of them. Then I have also inserted a common user for both of the companies.

```
{
    "companyId": 1,
    "companyName": "ABC company",
    "companyUsers": [
        {
            "companyUserMappingId": 1,
            "company": 1,
            "user": {
                "userId": 1,
                "email": "sachintendulkar@gmail.com",
                "companyUserMapping": [
                    1
                ]
            },
            "active": true,
            "external": false
        },
        {
            "companyUserMappingId": 3,
            "company": 1,
            "user": {
                "userId": 3,
                "email": "shanewarne@gmail.com",
                "companyUserMapping": [
                    3,
                    {
                        "companyUserMappingId": 4,
                        "company": {
                            "companyId": 2,
                            "companyName": "XYZ company",
                            "companyUsers": [
                                {
                                    "companyUserMappingId": 2,
                                    "company": 2,
                                    "user": {
                                        "userId": 2,
                                        "email": "sehwag@gmail.com",
                                        "companyUserMapping": [
                                            2
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "active": true,
                                    "external": false
                                },
                                4
                            ]
                        },
                        "user": 3,
                        "active": true,
                        "external": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            "active": true,
            "external": false
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above JSON, ABC and XYZ are two companies and a common user for both of the companies is shanewarne@gmail.com

As mentioned in the summary If I try to pull a particular company(ABC company) and associated users, it also brings another company and users which is unrelated.

To resolve this problem I have Implemented like below

```
public CompanyDto getConsolidatedCompanyData(Long companyId) {
Company existingCompany = companyRepository.findById(companyId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Company not found for the companyId :: "+companyId));
        CompanyDto companyDto=new CompanyDto();
        companyDto.setCompanyId(existingCompany.getCompanyId());
        companyDto.setCompanyName(existingCompany.getCompanyName());
        Set<CompanyUserMappingDto> companyUserMappingDtoList=new LinkedHashSet<>();
        Set<CompanyUserMapping> companyUserMappingList=existingCompany.getCompanyUserMapping();
        for (CompanyUserMapping cum : companyUserMappingList) {
            CompanyUserMappingDto companyUserMappingDto=new CompanyUserMappingDto();
            companyUserMappingDto.setCompanyUserMappingId(cum.getCompanyUserMappingId());
            CompanyUserDto cdto=new CompanyUserDto();
            cdto.setUserId(cum.getUser().getUserId());
            cdto.setEmail(cum.getUser().getEmail());
            companyUserMappingDto.setUser(cdto);
            companyUserMappingDto.setActive(cum.isActive());
            companyUserMappingDto.setExternal(cum.isExternal());
            companyUserMappingDtoList.add(companyUserMappingDto);
        }
        companyDto.setAssociatedUsers(companyUserMappingDtoList);
        return companyDto;
        
    }
```

In the same way, if I try to fetch a particular user and associated company I am getting related data so I have implemented code

```
private UserDto getConslidatedUserData(Long userId) {
User existingUser = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found for the userId :: "+userId));
        Set<UserCompanyMappingDto> associatedCompanies=new HashSet<>();
        UserDto userDto=new UserDto();
        userDto.setUserId(existingUser.getUserId());
        userDto.setEmail(existingUser.getEmail());
        Set<CompanyUserMapping> companyUserMapping=existingUser.getCompanyUserMapping();
        for (CompanyUserMapping companyUserMapping2 : companyUserMapping) {
            UserCompanyMappingDto userCompanyMappingDto=new UserCompanyMappingDto();
            userCompanyMappingDto.setCompanyUserMappingId(companyUserMapping2.getCompanyUserMappingId());
            UserCompanyDto userCompanyDto=new UserCompanyDto();
            userCompanyDto.setCompanyId(companyUserMapping2.getCompany().getCompanyId());
            userCompanyDto.setCompanyName(companyUserMapping2.getCompany().getCompanyName());
            userCompanyMappingDto.setCompany(userCompanyDto);
            associatedCompanies.add(userCompanyMappingDto);
        }
        userDto.setAssociatedCompanies(associatedCompanies);
        return userDto;
    }
```

Do I need to improvise Implementation for the first two cases?

Comment: @Erik Lucio Please check this